# Send code from Global.asax file to default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, global-asax

I have a default.aspx page that sometimes will cause an exception that gets caught in the Global.asax file. How do I send data back to my default.aspx page to change the HTML output without doing a page refresh? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to implement a try catch and then detect the error and take steps accordingly
so suppose you know in which line you have an error.

```
try
{
 //error prone code
}
catch
{
 reponse.write("error");
 response.End()
}
```

doing this you will catch the error and it wont be caught in the global.asax file and the `"error"` string would be sent back as response to the user
*NOTE - this is just an example and th estructure of the code might differ widely depending upon the type of request `GET` OR `POST` or even if thats and `AJAX` based request

Comment: it is an HttpException (timed out) so i believe that is supposed to be caught at the application level (Global.asax)

Comment: then probably a response.write in the global.asax would solve this